# Need help finding and printing the versions of all modules used?

Tags: python, module, version

I am trying to set up a regression test suite and incorporate the system configuration at runtime.  The following code finds most of the modules used by the system (and their versions):

```
import pkg_resources
import sys
for m in sys.modules:
    try:
        ml.append(m+'-'+pkg_resources.get_distribution(m).version)
    except:
        pass
print "# modules used:",sort(ml)
```

which returns:

```
# modules used: ['IPython-4.0.0', 'PIL-1.1.7', 'bottleneck-1.0.0',
'decorator-4.0.2', 'ipykernel-4.0.3', 'ipython_genutils-0.1.0',
'jupyter_client-4.0.0', 'jupyter_core-4.0.4', 'matplotlib-1.4.3',
'numexpr-2.4.3', 'numpy-1.9.2', 'pandas-0.16.2', 'pexpect-3.3',
'pickleshare-0.5', 'pyparsing-2.0.3', 'pysal-1.10.0', 'pytz-2015.4',
'scipy-0.16.0', 'simplegeneric-0.8.1', 'six-1.9.0', 'tornado-4.2.1',
'traitlets-4.0.0', 'xlsxwriter-0.7.3']
```

But there are not all of them.  A quick check of the following:

```
ml = ['sklearn-'+sklearn.__version__,
      'osgeo-'+osgeo.__version__]
print "# package versions:",sort(ml)
```

returns:

```
# package versions: ['osgeo-2.0.0' 'sklearn-0.16.1']
```

which are installed and used in the main scripts.  I should also add that some of the reported modules like tornado and xlsxwriter and not called or used directly, while some of the ones which are imported directly into the code were not found.

Does anyone know a trick to report jut the ones which are called from the scripts, or at least one that does not miss important ones?